# How to set selection backGround for the entire section in u itable view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I Have a table view with multiple sections as follows..

[image]

I know how to set background color for the selecting a Cell / row

But i need to fill the selection to the entire section instead of individual cell selections

is it possible if yes how any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the section value from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate of tableview and change the background color of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dataSource method of `UITableview`

in Header File

```
NSUInteger index;
```

in Implemention File (.m)

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
index=-1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CELL_IDENTIFIER";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    }

        if (indexPath.section==index) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
        }
        else{
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        }
       cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d Section %d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
       return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    index=indexPath.section;
    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

i hope its working....

```
 - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     NSIndexPath *currentSelectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     if (currentSelectedIndexPath != nil)
     {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath] setBackgroundColor:NotSelectedCellBGColor];
     }

     return indexPath;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setBackgroundColor:SelectedCellBGColor];
  }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   if (cell.isSelected == YES)
   {
       [cell setBackgroundColor:SelectedCellBGColor];
   }
   else
   {
       [cell setBackgroundColor:setBackgroundColor:NotSelectedCellBGColor];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
int currentSection;
```

.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    currentSection = indexPath.section;
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( currentSection == indexPath.section ) {
        cell.backgroundColor = SelectedColor;
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = OtherColor;
    }
}
```